# How to get colour variations

Tags: colors, user-interface, hexadecimal

I've got a colour scheme based on this link http://colorschemedesigner.com/#0141EmAMqnBmd

I need a total of 6 colours divided into 2 groups based on just two of the outlined colours below. Apologies in advanced as I have no idea on the technical terms relating to colour/shade/hue etc.

**Group 1**

1st colour = #FFFF8683
2nd colour = ?lighter
3rd colour = ?lightest

**Group 2**

1st colour = #FF7BEF82
2nd colour = ?lighter
3rd colour = ?lightest

[image]

How can I calculate the Hex values so that the 2nd and 3rd colour of each group are the same shade as the 1st but lighter, with 2nd colour being lighter than 1st and 3rd colour being lighter than 2nd?

Essentially I want to create lighter shades of the same colour but equal distance apart? (Currently don't know distance apart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention the software available to you to choose the colors. You are dealing with RGB color now, but two color models that would make this more intuitive for you are HSL and LAB.

One might select a hex color (RGB color model) using a tool that can convert between color models, and then specify a specific lightness adjustment (basically the L in HSL and LAB), and then reference the resultant RGB hex code(s) for the lighter shade(s). So you can decide that you want all colors to be 1.2x lighter than the previous one, you just take the L value and multiply by 1.2.

Not all color models support the same color ranges however, so you might have color shifts when converting between models. In fact you can count on it.

Comment: If you don't feel this is the right approach, perhaps the terms used might help you refine your search

Comment: Excellent - thank you. I've managed to find this site http://hslpicker.com/#FF8683, based on suggested keywords, which has exactly what I need.